# Use a separation theorem to show: $Ax=b$ has a solution $\Leftrightarrow (c^TA=0\Rightarrow c^Tb=0)$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}, b \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}^n.$ Show that $Ax=b$ has a solution if and only for all $c$ with $c^TA=0$ it holds that $c^Tb=0$ as well.

The exercise seems quiet easy using linear algebra, but I don't understand how to solve it with separation theorems.

EDIT: I need to use separation theorems for both directions

Comment: There is a problem: if $n\neq m,$ then $c^TA$ is ill-defined, and if you take $c\in\mathbb{R}^m,$ then it is $c^Tb$ to be ill-defined.

Comment: Isn't $c^TA \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times m}$?

Comment: One direction is straigthforward: if $Ax=b$ has a solution and $c^TA=0$, then we have $c^T Ax=c^T b$. Substituting $c^T A = 0$ yields $c^TAx=0 x=0 =c^Tb$.

Comment: I made an edit, I need to use seperation theorems for both directions